# Middle centered text inline

Tags: css

How to center vertically small text after a bigger one? I dont want to rely on some constant height. Is it possible?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="big">Big</span>
    <span class="small">Small</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.big {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.small {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Luis gets you most of the way there but the small text still sits too high. If you add a line height to the small text and vertical align it down a little it sits perfectly.

```
.big {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.small {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: -25%;
}
```

Comment: Great it works. I was thinking though if its possible to mix different vertiacl-align in one line? Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/xL7ts32j/2/ The expected result will be to have second "Small" element aligned top without touching the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align` rule on class `.big`

**CSS**

```
.big {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

> The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to
>   each other on a line are lined up

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xL7ts32j/1/)**